# Understanding iOS Provisioning Profiles

Tags: ios, certificate, provisioning-profile

My understanding is that Provisioning Profiles are used to prevent your app from being installed and used on devices not authorized by you. However, I don't see how this can be enforced since anyone can create the profile they need.


If I wanted to run app `com.company.app`, all I need to create the profile is the app id, which I have(`com.company.app`), the UUID of the phone I want to run it in, which I have because it's my phone, and the certificate of the developer which is not supposed to be secret since it holds the public key.


So, what's keeping me from creating my own profile, installing it on my phone and run the app without the developer's authorization?

Comment: So, what's keeping me from creating my own profile, installing it on my phone and run the app without the developer's authorization? - Tell me how do you get access to a project or ipa files? This is what keeping you. You have nothing to run if you're not a developer. You don't have access to developer's account to create profile for a particular bundle id

Comment: @AndreyChernukha That's not the point, the profile is supposed to prevent you from using the app when you already have the installation package.

Comment: with the app already installed - how are you supposed to install it?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha The file you give testers along with the profile to install the app?

Comment: so they are never able to install the ipa without profile. This is what profile for

Comment: @AndreyChernukha Not if the ipa comes with a profile not containing the right UUID.

Comment: i just can't get what exactly is confusing you. You know what is profile for. So what is your question?

Comment: @AndreyChernukha That I can unzip the ipa file, change the profile in it while keeping the certificate intact and then install the app wherever I want. So, what's the point of having the profile in the first place?

Comment: Lianes can you please give me a link on how to change profile in ipa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand the point of the provisioning profiles. The point is not to prevent unauthorized users from running your app. The point is to make it difficult for you to distribute your app outside of the App Store by limiting the number of devices you can install it on.

Comment: It does limit you, but I'm pretty sure that it is also there to allow developers distribute the app to testers while preventing it from being copied to unauthorized devices.

Comment: That's a side effect. And a bad one in the view of most developers. We generally want to be able to install the app on more devices than Apple allows.

Comment: Regardless, that leaves the question unanswered. What's the point of having the profiles to begin with, if I can always unzip the ipa file and change the profile in it to include the UUID of whatever phone I want to install it in?

Comment: That's my point. The provisioning profile system isn't designed to prevent that. If someone gets the unencrypted IPA, yes they can modify it (and/or the profile), re-sign it, and install it on another device. In order to do so though, you'd need a dev account, and would need to put the new device's UDID in the dev portal. Apple is fine with that. And the profile system is only a benefit to Apple, not to devs. It's a pain that we learn to work with.

Comment: IPA files are not encrypted though, the .app file inside the .ipa file is. So, you can do this with any .ipa file.

Comment: If you want to get into the details, it's actually the executable in the .app file that is encrypted. And you would need to decrypt it in order to re-sign it. Signing the encrypted file won't work.

Comment: I don't have to re-sign it. I just have to change the `embedded.mobileprovision` file to add the UUID I want.

Comment: If you change the `embedded.mobileprovision` without re-signing, it will fail the verification when launched on the device and just exit. Unless you're using a jailbroken device, which changes the whole discussion.

Comment: Why? If the certificate never changed in the `embedded.mobileprovision` file?

Comment: Every file in the .IPA is signed, changing any one, including the profile, breaks the signature. Look inside a .app file, you'll see the signatures in `_CodeSignature/CodeResources`.

Comment: Oh boy... so let me get this. The `embedded.mobileprovision` is also signed, but somehow the certificate is left intact so that you can actually read it. If I wanted to modify `embedded.mobileprovision`, I would have to re-sign the file, which I can't because I'm missing the private key, so everything falls apart. Is that right?

Comment: I'm still confused since I can still create my own profile with their app id, my UUID and their certificate and use it to install the app in my unauthorized device without modifying the ipa itself. But hey, whatever, I'm quitting on trying to understand this for today. Thanks for your help anyway.